# Recording Gear VR with Android MediaRecorder and Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mediarecorder, gear-vr

I'm trying to record gameplay of a Unity3d game. I have set up a MediaRecorder which records the screen of normal games correctly. However, when it comes to Gear VR, the video only gets the first frame and then is still. Audio still records correctly.

Is there some technical difference in how VR is displayed in a Unity game? I thought it was just a combination of 2 cameras in the Unity side of things, but when it came to rendering it on the lower level side nothing would change as far as Android is concerned.

There must be something different with the surface that gets rendered to, but I can't find any documentation or anything to help with my search! Can anyone help me out here?

The media recorder code is pretty standard. I'm highlighting the key parts here in case there is something specific to my settings... but it is working with normal 3D scenes. Really I'm just looking guidance as to why Gear VR scenes don't seem to record and what I need to investigate to help remedy the issue

**Getting the projection manager:**

```
mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activityContext.getSystemService
                    (Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
```

**Creating the intent:**

```
startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), 1);
```

**Creating the media recorder:**

```
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

**Creating the virtual display:**

```
mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("ScreenRecord",
            mDisplayWidth, mDisplayHeight, mScreenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null /*Handler*/);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the Samsung device. I have the similar things happened and the current workaround is to avoid initialize the AUDIO part! Just enable the video but don't set Audio source and avoid the request for Mic in the manifest file. This can make the video recording work. I tried this setting in Unity but not Gear VR.